# How To Deploy .NET Web Project in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-applications, deployment, prerequisites

I am developing a .NET Web application in Visual Studio 2010. It is in preliminary stage and so far I have implemented the ASP.NET authentication. I have a database ASPNETDB attached with the Solution of the Visual Studio(it appears when I did ASP.NET configuration from Visual Studio Project->ASP.NET Configuration). So far I am testing the application by the help of Visual Studio's Integrated Server and I haven't installed any other software like SQL Server Management Studio etc.

I am running in Windows 7 64 bit and I want to test publishing the application in IIS 7.0. IIS is already installed. Also I have installed

- SQL Server System CLR Type
- SQL Server Native Client
- SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Objects
- Web Deployement Tool 2.1

I am going to follow instruction as shown in [Deployment to a Hosting Provider: Deploying to IIS as a Test Environment](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider/deployment-to-a-hosting-provider-deploying-to-iis-as-a-test-environment-5-of-12)

So before that, I want to know do I need anything else to install or configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're good to go. Just follow the instructions carefully and you'll be ok!

Comment: Thanks. Everything went fine, but when I browse the application from IIS I got the error: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\inetpub\wwwroot\EMSApplication\App_Data\ASPNETDB.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share. Also there is no App_Data folder and the database in the IIS. How can I solve this?

Comment: I found the problem. While publishing from VS2010 the App_Data folder was not copied so I move this database manually. And then I got another error, that the database is in read-only mode and I found there had been two new User added in the security permission of the database, which is IUSER and IIS_IUSER. I had increased the permissions of both of them to Full and also added an User NETWORK_SERVICE with full privilege. Then the database problem got solved. But since I am using Spring.Net the web.config contains open-session-in-view and the Pages are extended from Spring.Web.UI.Page class...

Comment: This gave me another error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. That means the instantiation of some classes, needed for dependency injection was failed, so I changed the Managed Pipeline Mode of DefaultApplicationPool to Classic from Integrated. And this problem thus was solved.

Comment: There was also another error I had, which is System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers and the reason was that I had added <trust level="Medium"/> entry in web.config. After removal of it solves the problem. And lastly the nhibernate gave me another error, I am unable to re-generate it, but second time it worked fine. Now the application is running in localhost. Am I did everything right? Thanks